# android: fast way do deal with comprssed strings

Tags: android, performance, text, io, nio

I have a number of compressed String(1.5M each) stored in a file. I need to read them out, and do some computation on them. Basically, here is what I did:

```
public static Object fetchRSFB(File inFile) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    GZIPInputStream gs = null;
    Object result = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        gs = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(gs);
        MyBWT.rankArray = (int[]) ois.readObject();
        String str= (String) ois.readObject();
        //do something with the string
```

The only problem is, the performance of the code is quite slow in general, so I am thinking 2 options:

1. to use NIO to map the compressed file into memory, and do the above on the memory compressed file(I heard that this may be achievable, but I have no idea if it really is)
2. Instead of storing objects, I could just store binary compressed version of the text and then read the text, I heard that it may be fast then ObjectInputStream.

Anyone knows a way of achieving the above options? or is there a better way, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using `DeflatorOutputStream and InflatorInputStream` see [Fast compression in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918189/fast-compression-in-java/3918970#3918970)